# How to pack a repeated protobuf message into an Any

Tags: java, kotlin, protocol-buffers

I'm working with a third party service that consumes a `com.google.protobuf.Any`. I need to pass in a `repeated Message myObject` object, but how does one pack a repeated protobuf field into an Any?

I'm writing a Kotlin extension function along the lines of `fun List<Message>.toProtobufAny(): com.google.protobuf.Any {...}` to (hopefully) make this generic for any Message because I'll be sending in a variety of repeated message types. My first attempts have been to implement an `Any.pack(RepeatedFieldBuilder<>)`, but haven't been successful yet with the syntax. Not finding very many code example out there on this specific use case.

Thanks.

*Edit to include example*

@ILYAS_Kerbal

I set up a basic message to hold a repeated list of Anys

```
message RepeatedAny {
    repeated google.protobuf.Any values = 1;
}
```

And then created a couple extension functions to support it...

```
/**
 * Given a list of protobuf messages, create a protobuf.Any
 */
fun List<Message>.toProtoAny(): Any {
    val repeatedAny = RepeatedAny.newBuilder().addAllValues(
        this.map { msg -> msg.toProtoAny() }
    ).build()

    return repeatedAny.toProtoAny()
}

/**
 * Pack a protobuf.Message into a protobuf.Any
 */
fun Message.toProtoAny(): Any = this.packAny()

/**
 * Pack a protobuf.Message into a protobuf.Any
 */
private fun Message.packAny(): Any =
    Any.pack(this, "$defaultAnyLibrary/${this.javaClass.name}")
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `Any` contains a single proto, not a repeated field.

You can create a `List<Any>`, your own `AnyRepeated` proto, or an `Any` containing a proto that has a `repeated` proto field for your chosen message type, but you cannot pack more than one proto into an `Any`.

Comment: For anyone else, the `your own AnyRepeated proto` workaround was the one I implemented.

Comment: @romanpilot can you share an example?

Comment: @ILYAS_Kerbal Updated original post to include an example implementation